# Can anybody relate this title with the article?

Tags: meaning-in-context, headlinese

the title:

"Closing Up Shop on a Marriage"

the article:

https://www.nytimes.com/2022/04/08/style/modern-love-closing-up-shop-on-a-marriage.html

My question about this is:

the main character of this narrative got separated from her husband, so I don't get the "on marriage" part.

not a big text though.

Comment: I can't access the source here, but "to close up shop on X* is an "unusual" usage that basically means *to **end** X* (to stop using or endorsing X). The narrator is presumably describing how her marriage failed / became "irrelevant".

Comment: In the UK, the more alliterative 'shut up shop' is quite common. "I am not saying that we should shun qualifications and shut up shop on our careers."

Answer (score 1):

**Close up shop** is an [idiom](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/close-up-shop) that means to end something. It's typically used when referring to a business or business activity.

In this case, the author is referring to a marriage like you might refer to a business arrangement. This usage is very informal and not very common.

Comment: The writer of the story is using the idiom in the stronger sense of *taking care of the last details before closing permanently* and means it as a metaphor for her former marriage: the shared rewards card is the last detail that she cannot bring herself to take care of.